# Online store with support for store credit

Tags: django, shopping-cart, satchmo, online-store

I am looking into online stores to use internally at a company. They would like to be able to add credit to a users account as part of an incentive program.

I have started looking at Online store software, but am not clear as to which support store credit, or if it is a function of the payment module (ie separate issue).

The credit shouldn't be in the form of actual money (so it shouldn't be like putting money on a users paypal account), but credit which can be redeemed in-store.

Comment: hopefully that makes the question clearer

Comment: honestly i have not seen any such functionality,but i believe you can do something like credit points which user can redeem at his/her own will

Comment: This is something that you'll need to write yourself. Something like Satchmo is only going to support actual currencies.

Comment: What about stores that support gift codes. Are there open source stores that support that?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this easily in Satchmo with the Giftcertificate-Module. You can assign a GiftCertificate an amount of money and the user owning this code can use it on checkout to pay. If the cart-amount is less, then the GC can be used afterwards with the rest-money on it. And if it isn't enough money on it, the user can pay the rest with any other payment method available.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) has this functionallity built into their commercial editions.